# Visual Studio 2008 Debugger Has Gone South

Tags: visual-studio-2008, dll, debugging

Dell Dimension 5621 - Win XP SP2 VS Studio 6.0 & 2008. We support ASP pages.

Usually I have had no problems using Visual Studio 2008 debugger with ASP pages from VStudio 6.0. In fact, up until last week, worked great. I was actually commenting to boss week ago wish that debugger had been around when VS 6.0 came out 10 years or so ago.

Then the system degraded. Started getting crashes with Debugger. Thought perhaps might be symantec AV. So I disabled those services. Now, when a bug happens, the debugger loads and ask me if I want to attach to dllhost.exe to debug.

You can attach or say no. If you attach, the system will debug; however, upon exiting will crash devenv.exe and kill most of the time the debugger and VS 6.0 sometimes which is annoying when your editing script based code to say the least.

Similiar to this issue this user reported here:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=352867

> Error:
>
> AppName: devenv.exe AppVer: 9.0.30729.1 AppStamp:488f2b50
>
> ModName: vsdebug.dll ModVer: 9.0.30729.1 ModStamp:488f2c04
>
> fDebug: 0 Offset: 0001f1c2

This system did not exhibit these issues up until about a week ago. As far as we are aware, there have been no changes to this system. Scanned with several AV programs as well.

When attaching to debugger:

> Attaching to this process can potentially harm your computer. If the information below looks suspicious or you are unsure, do not attach to this process.
>
> Name: C:\Windows\system32\dllhost.exe
>
> User: \IWAM_
>
> Do you wish to attach to this process?
>
> Attach Don't Attach.

As far as I know nothing has been done to this system. We've scanned with AV programs and clean. I would think if this were a virus the debugger would never even fire up and/or the dllhost.exe would be reporting from the wins directory like I've read about dllhost.exe viruses.

Any suggestions would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Are you running as the admin?

Answer (score 1):

The standard **bad** answer usually is uninstall and then reinstall visual studio.  Annoying answer too as it doesn't really explain what happened.

Answer (score 1):

Check out MS hotfix at http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/kb967631.

There is no KB-article yet, but any update related to the debugger is worth a try in this situation. It cannot get any worse...

Answer (score 0):

When programs start to crash consistently when they never did before, I usually start out by clearing C:\Windows\Temp. I remember back in the WinNT days, that solved almost all printer related issues, as well as old InstallShield installation issues :-)

Answer (score 0):

Go download Debugging Tools for Windows, start WinDbg, and attach it to VS - it should give you more info as to what's happening (or at least a clue on what to look at further)